# Issue With grunt-contrib-sass

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, gruntjs

I am having an issue with Grunt's `grunt-contrib-sass` package that I am just overlooking. When it compiles my sass, I want it to go into my css directory and not create a sass directory in the css directory. This is what I have now after `grunt-contrib-sass` compiles. I don't want it to add the `sass` directory in the `css` directory when it compiles:

```
- css
    - sass (I don't want this level)
        - default
            - index.css
- sass
    - default
        - index.scss
        - fonts.scss
- Gruntfile.js
- grunt
    - watch.js
    - sass.js
```

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    var options = {
        config: {
            src: './grunt/*.js'
        },
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')
    };

    var config = require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, options);

    grunt.initConfig(config);

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
};
```

sass.js

```
module.exports = {
    skins: {
        options: {
            style: 'compressed'
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            src: ["sass/**/index.scss"],
            dest: "css/",
            ext: '.css'
        }]
    }
};
```

watch.js

```
module.exports = {
    sass: {
        files: [
            'sass/**/*.scss',
        ],
        tasks: ['sass'],
        options: {
            livereload: true
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as `sass.js`.

```
module.exports = {
    skins: {
        options: {
            style: 'compressed'
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'sass/default',
            src: 'index.scss',
            dest: 'css/',
            ext: '.css'
        }]
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Will test this and let you know. I deleted my grunt stuff and wrote my own precompiler because grunt wasn't doing what I wanted. lol! Will test!

Comment: @MaxBaldwin Any luck? ;)

Comment: I ended up doing it on my own. I used the ```fs``` module's watch command to watch my sass files and then I think I compiled them with a sass npm. I can't seem to find the code I ended up with.

Comment: I revisited this method, but using grunt-browserify. This seems to be a universal way to name files dynamically. Thanks again!